# C++ method overriding

Tags: c++, overriding

Is the Wikipedia example at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding_%28programming%29) article about method overiding in C++ correct?

Please see the code below where I have mentioned a comment //INCORRECT

Slightly confused about overiding in C++ and run time polymorphism. What should this cast do?

```
#include <iostream>

class Rectangle {
public:
    explicit Rectangle(double l, double w) : length(l), width(w) {}
    virtual void print() const;

private:
    double length;
    double width;
};

void Rectangle::print() const { // print() method of base class
   std::cout << "Length = " << this->length << "; Width = " << this->width;
}

class Box : public Rectangle {
public:
    explicit Box(double l, double w, double h) : Rectangle(l, w), height(h) {}
    virtual void print() const; // virtual is optional here, but it is a good practice to remind it to the developer

private:
    double height;
};

void Box::print() const { // print() method of derived class
   Rectangle::print();  // Invoke parent print() method.
   std::cout << "; Height= " << this->height;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   Rectangle rectangle(5.0, 3.0);   rectangle.print();
   // outputs:
   // Length = 5.0; Width = 3.0

   Box box(6.0, 5.0, 4.0);
   // the pointer to the most overridden method in the vtable in on Box::print
   //box.print(); // but this call does not illustrate overriding

   static_cast<Rectangle&>(box).print(); // this one does   

   // outputs:
   // Length = 5.0; Width = 3.0; Height= 4 // INCORRECT  

   //But it actually outputs Length = 6; Width = 5; Height = 4

   getchar();
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yes, the particular values are wrong. - Personally I would have thought the call illustrates dynamic dispatch, and overriding actually means providing an override.

Comment: It looks like the wiki's expected output is wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line: `static_cast<Rectangle&>(box).print();` has same effect as this code would have:

```
Rectangle & r = box;
r.print();
```

and also same effect as this code would have:

```
Rectangle * r = &box;
r->print();
```

It means that Box object was created (`Box box(6.0, 5.0, 4.0);` = in runtime you see `Box`) and it doesn't matter what is the type of pointer / reference where you store this object. The fact that you store box as a `Rectangle*` is what you see in compile time.

Most important fact about overriding virtual methods is that about "which method will be called?" is decided in runtime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You're right - the output mentioned is incorrect.

The cast simply demonstrates that a box is a kind of rectangle (inheriting from it) and that even as a rectangle, the method override will still be effective and the `Box` version of the `print` method will be called.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to fix the comment in Wikipedia: the output should indeed be `Length = 6; Width = 5; Height = 4`.

The other part is correct, though: the code where a `Box.print()` is called even after the `Box` reference has been statically cast to a reference to its superclass is indeed a demonstration of how overriding of a virtual method works in C++.

Another way to demonstrate the same point is through use of a pointer instead of a reference:

```
Rectangle *boxPtr = &box;
boxPtr->print();
```

Comment: Thanks to you ahd @Liho. So I can revert back to my previous non-confused state.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in the article was indeed wrong (and has now been fixed); it should have printed 6,5, and 4 as you say.

The point of the cast is to demonstrate that, even if you call the virtual function via a reference to the base class (`Rectangle`), it will call the override associated with the actual type of the object (`Box`) - you still get the three values printed by `Box::print()`, rather than the two printed by `Rectangle::print()`.